# Image preprocessing: How to resize / align / cut images of various sizes?

Tags: cnn, image-classification, preprocessing, image-recognition

I want to create a new dataset for image recognition.

If I have *Object A* that I want to recognize in images, and multiple images of various different sizes, how do I preprocess them so that

1. they are of same size
2. aligned (occurences of *Object A* rotated appropriately)
3. zoomed in / out, depending on how big *Object A* occurence is
   ?

And what would be the best way to solve the problem when there are multiple occurences of *Object A* on a single image?

Comment: For points 2 and 3, I think you will need to manually align and zoom in/out the data.